# Is there any solution in R to assign TRUE/FALSE to first occurrence (observed the current period and not the one before)

Tags: r, indexing, indicator

I define first occurrence as observing one variable in the current period, but not in the period before (1 period is equivalent to 1 year).

Therefore, in the following example, I want to check if the company product, V3 (third column), is observed for first time (following the definition I gave before) taking into account the time-variable, V2 (second column).

```
a <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,2005,2006,2007,2009,2010, "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"), ncol = 3))
```

I want to create a new column indicator (solution would be V4) that accounts for the first occurrence (observation in the current period , that it was not observed on the period before, )

```
b <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,2005,2006,2007,2009,2010, "A", "B", "A", "A", "A","TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"), ncol = 4))
```

I have tried with min() function as well as with crazy loops. But I did not come up with the appropriate solution.

Note: V1 represents the company id. In my database I have thousands of different companies

Any clue?

Regards

Comment: The idea is: I sell bananas on first year 2005, and in years 2009 and 2010. Then I want to assign "TRUE" only to the years 2005 and 2009. Assigning "FALSE" to 2010 because in this year, bananas were not a new product (it was exported the period before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Company Year Product
1 2005  A
1 2006  B
1 2007  A
1 2009  A
1 2010  A")

DT[, yearBef := Year - 1L]
DT[, NotInLastYear := DT[DT, on=.(Company, Product, Year=yearBef), 
    fcoalesce(x.Year==i.Year, TRUE)]]
```

Comment: Thank for your helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly. Try to do it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>% 
  group_by(V2, V3) %>% 
  mutate(V4 = row_number() == 1)
```

Comment: Last year was 2010 (not 2009). I don't have duplicates in my data

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for :

```
a$V4 <- !duplicated(a)
```

Comment: Last year was 2010 (not 2009). I don't have duplicates in my data